# JAVASCRIPT could somebody help me with this code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-else

I'm trying to set a conditional page load on a Form Submit, following "If users select [x + y] option, send them to [x] page".
I'm really not that familiar with JavaScript, how should i do?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="choice">
   Geographic area 
       <select name="geoarea" size="1">
            <option value="area"> Select </option>

            <option value="1"> Europe, America, Oceania </option>
            <option value="2"> Eastern Asia </option>
            <option value="3"> Middle East </option>    
       </select> <br>

   Type of itinerary 
      <select name="itinerary" size="1">
            <option value=""> Select </option> 

            <option value="4"> Arts-Cultural </option>
            <option value="5"> Religious </option>
            <option value="6"> Wine and Food </option>
            <option value="7"> Seaside </option>
            <option value="8"> Naturalistic </option>
      </select> <br>

   <form method="post" action="url_script">
      <input type="submit" name="continue" value="continue">

   </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: The obligatory, "what have you tired"?

Comment: There is no JavaScript in your sample and your title is not according the SO rules..so it's all not good.

Comment: "I'm really not that familiar with JavaScript, how should i do" --- next time you visit your dentist ask them to do it for free just because you are not familiar with that. I'm sure it will also work with your car mechanic.

Comment: What do you mean `[x+y]` option?

Comment: i mean that if one selects geographic area(x) and type of itinerary (y), one will be sent to a different HTML page

Answer (score 0):

instead of submit form , use a submit button, when clicked ,call a ajax call to the 'url_script' or whatever page u want... ajax call can send info to the called page and get info back to javascript call.

Also if u just want to open a new page when something is selected, use window.open("new_page_url")....

```
<input type=button onclick="somefunction()">

somefunction()
{ window.open("new_page"); 
}
```